# Combine multiple SQL statements into a single one

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I combine these statements in a single SQL statement?

```
select city from station where city like 'a%';

select city from station where city like 'e%';

select city from station where city like 'i%';

select city from station where city like 'o%';

select city from station where city like 'u%';
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 5):

The obvious method is `union all`:

```
select city from station where city like 'a%' union all
select city from station where city like 'e%' union all
. . .
```

Perhaps almost as obvious is:

```
where city like 'a%' or city like 'e%' or . . .
```

You could also use a different approach, such as:

```
where left(city, 1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

(Note:  not all databases support `left()`.)

The more typical method would be some form of regular expression, but that syntax depends on the database.

Answer (score 1):

`where SUBSTR(city,1,1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')` or use `left(city, 1)` if your database supports it.

You could always use `union`/`union all` between the statements, or `like 'a%' or  like 'e%' ....` but i prefer using `substr` or `left` in such cases

Comment: substr, left ... wouldn't benefit from indexes (unless someone thinks to create an index like left(city,1)).

Comment: @Cetin Basoz: That's true, but with multiple `LIKE` conditions it may very well be that a mere full table scan is much faster than muddeling one's way through an index.

Comment: Yes but even with a table scan a simple OR approach is best.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best method, which also would utilize existing index would be to use OR:

```
select city from station 
where 
  city like 'a%' OR 
  city like 'e%' OR
  city like 'i%' OR
  city like 'o%' OR
  city like 'u%';
```

NOTE: In MS SQL server and postgreSQL this generates the best execution plan.